# Why does .flaskenv variables not work with uWSGI but does by running flask by itself?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, dotenv

I have an interesting problem and I would appreciate if anybody can help me understand logically why this happens.  I am creating a simple web application with flask and using a virtual environment for all (literally every specific python package and not installing anything extra for my OS) things.  When I load my development script with `python app.py` the app will recognize the variables in `.flaskenv` but not when I load my uwsgi server.  I am using `pip install python-dotenv` in my virtual environment as well as `pip install uwsgi` and uwsgi is not installed on my system, neither local or remote and neither is dotenv.

I am unable to conjure why this would happen exactly, can you help please?  I don't know where to go from here.  Here's a bit of my code:

#### at the top of my app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = uuid.uuid4().hex
musicdir = os.environ.get('MUSIC_DIR')
```

#### in my .flaskenv:

```
# development?
FLASK_ENV=production
# index.py?
FLASK_APP=app.py
# /home/user/Music/?
MUSIC_DIR=static/music
MUSICLIST_PASS=iamapasswd
DBUPDATE_PASS=ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffQ/
```

I was expecting it to 'just work' and since this happened I do not know where to go from here at all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.